# Shape of target and predictions tensors in PyTorch loss functions

Tags: python, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am confused with the input shapes for tensors in `nn.CrossEntropyLoss`.
I am trying to implement a simple autoencoder for text sequences. The core of my problem can be illustrated by the following code

```
predictions = torch.rand(2, 3, 4)
target = torch.rand(2, 3)
print(predictions.shape)
print(target.shape)
nn.CrossEntropyLoss(predictions.transpose(1, 2), target)
```

In my case predictions has the shape `(time_step, batch_size, vocabulary_size)` while target has the shape `(time_step, batch_size)`. Next I am transposing the predictions as per [description](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) which says that the second dimension of predictions should be the number of classes - vocabulary_size in my case. The code returns an error `RuntimeError: bool value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous`. Could someone please enlighten me how to use the damn thing? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the loss function, but you are building it. The signature of the [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) constructor is:

```py
nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=None, size_average=None, ignore_index=-100, reduce=None, reduction='mean')
```

You are setting the predictions as the `weight` and the target as `size_average`, 
where `weight` is an optional rescaling of the classes and `size_average` is deprecated, but expects a boolean. The target is a tensor of size *[2, 3]*, which cannot be converted to a boolean.

You need to create the loss function first, as you don't use any of the optional parameters of the constructor, you don't specify any of them.

```py
# Create the loss function
cross_entropy = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Call it to calculate the loss for your data
loss = cross_entropy(predictions.transpose(1, 2), target)
```

Alternatively, you can directly use the functional version [`nn.functional.cross_entropy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy):

```py
import torch.nn.functional as F

loss = F.cross_entropy(predictions.transpose(1, 2), target)
```

The advantage of the class version, compared to the functional version, is that you only need to specify the extra parameters once (such as the `weight`) instead of having to supply them manually each time.

Regarding the dimensions of the tensors, the batch size must be the first dimension, because the losses are averaged per element in the batch, so you have tensor of losses with size *[batch_size]*. If you used `reduction="none"`, you would get back theses losses per element in the batch, but by default (`reduction="mean"`) the mean of these losses is returned. That result would be different if the mean is taken across time steps rather than batches.

Lastly, the targets need to be the class indices, which means they need to have type `torch.long` not `torch.float`. In this randomly chosen example, you could create the random classes with [`torch.randint`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.randint).

```py
predictions = torch.rand(2, 3, 4)
target = torch.randint(4, (2, 3))

# Reorder the dimensions
# From: [time_step, batch_size, vocabulary_size]
# To: [batch_size, vocabulary_size, time_step]
predictions = predictions.permute(1, 2, 0)
# From: [time_step, batch_size]
# To: [batch_size, time_step]
target = target.transpose(0, 1)

F.cross_entropy(predictions, target)
```